# Does it make sense to use Threading for easy Tasks?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, simulation

Im writing a Software which should simulate some Airplane Systems, except Flight Dynamics, in VB.Net for an Entertainment Flight Simulator.

As example the Programm computes which simulated 'Circuit Breakers/Relays' should be open or closed depending on the available Power Sources which results in an short Function like:

```
If PwrSrc.avail = true and Breaker.hasFailed = false then

 Breaker.close 

End if
```

The Code should run every X ms, but the Software needs to compute other Systems Status like Oil, Pneumatic and so on aswell.

Does it make sense the run a Thread for each simulated System, or would it be faster by using a single Thread?

Later more functions will be added and the Systems will get more complex, like Pressure Values for the Hydraulic System or stored Battery Engery for the Electrical System as example. For the start it should only be a very basic simulation.

It is not a (huge) Problem for me if some Data is not available/valid for other Threads in the 'first' simulation Step. Like 'Electrical Hydraulic Pump Power Avail' is Set after the first 'Electrical System'-Thread finished and will not be the correct Value for the first run of the 'Hydraulic System'-Thread because it may use Data from the previous Simulation-Step.

Comment: You need to test. There's an overhead with each thread so you might be doing more harm than good for small tasks. Testing is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: If threading off the 'simple' tasks makes the implementation of your requirements easier, and performance adequate, then do it:)   Simplification of design/implementation is often not seen as a charactristic of multithreading, but it surely can be:)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can multi thread and also use event based for better usage of resources.
Use obserables and then subscribers to those events like oil check/and other events like what you have mentioned in your description.
Based on the event create a thread and that thread will process your request.
Use thread pool for better utilization of resources as well.
There is no exact use-case for threads. If you want to reduce the load of your main thread to some others then you can very well go ahead and implement it.
But before getting into the threads take a look at the below points,

1. am I going to share global variables among multiple threads ? then need to take care data synchronization
2. Use Thread pool as much as possible.
3. Use event based stuffs wherever necessary.
4. Dont forget to close the resources after the usage like closing the thread pools.
5. Based on your CPU cores set the size of the thread pool like no of cores * 2.

Answer (score -1):

From what you've posted, I'm going to say "no, it doesn't make sense to use threading for these easy tasks"

Making this multithreaded will add a significant layer of complexity to the program, and you'll tie yourself in knots (hah) keeping it all straight.

You're essentially programming a game, and cycling a few booleans/changing the appearance of some UI elements is something you can easily do (tens of) thousands of times a second in a single "game loop".. You don't need to "make it faster" because it can already massively outstrip the performance of the humans using it

If you start getting into things where there is some massive amount of CPU or disk work required to make it go, you can leverage the task-based asynchronous pattern to keep things responsive, UI wise, which abstracts away a lot of the complexity involved in making something "apparently multithreaded"

At some point you might feel like making the jump to multithreading, but I'd recommend you build something first, run with it, and switch only if you become sure there is an inherent problem that only multithreading can solve. These things are few and far between, and it's likely that even the most complex games you've played are not truly massively multithreaded